# Exchange a key and one of its values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a small example of exchanging a key and one of its values, but I did not make it work:

```
dict1 = {1: ['BB', 'CC', 'DD'], 2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG']}
print(dict1)

for key in dict1:
    for value in dict1[key]:
        if value == 'BB':
            temp = key
            key = value            
            value = temp

print(dict1)
```

Current output:

```
{1: ['BB', 'CC', 'DD'], 2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG']}
```

Desired output:

```
{BB: [1, 'CC', 'DD'], 2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG']}
```

I have used the `temp` to exchange the `value` and `key`, but why does the output does not change (keeps as same as the original `dict1`)?

Comment: The desired output doesn't make sense -- you can't have duplicate keys in a dict. `list1` is really a dict. I don't understand the logic here. Please clarify.

Comment: I recommend [Python visualization](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) and [Python names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to help you understand.

Comment: I think the question is clear, but it requires some amount of explanation of how Python fundamentally works as an answer.

Comment: A short answer would be: `key` and `value` are new variables here (i.e. they are copies of the original `key` and `value`).

Comment: [5.5. Dictionaries- It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:~:text=with%20the%20requirement%20that%20the%20keys%20are%20unique%20(within%20one%20dictionary))

Comment: [```No, each key in a dictionary should be unique. You can’t have two keys with the same value. Attempting to use the same key again will just overwrite the previous value stored. If a key needs to store multiple values, then the value associated with the key should be a list or another dictionary.```](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/can-a-dictionary-have-two-keys-of-the-same-value/351465)

Comment: @Giorgos Xou thanks Xou, I had made a mistake on this point, I have just updated the desired output. My intention is simply exchange the value of a key and one of its value:)

Comment: @Jānis Š.
Thanks, I think you get the point of the problem. If `key` and `value` are copies of the original `key` and `value`, how can I exchange the ´real key and value´ though?

Comment: @jarmod  thanks, the visualization is very helpful!

Comment: C/C++ approach is impossible in your case in Python. You cannot change the key - only add a new one or delete an existing one. To replace an item in the list, you can either create a new list and assign it to a key or use _ctypes (see an example here by martineau (the last answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205017/how-to-reference-a-dict-object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple homemade solution, create a new result dict is better than change old dict.

code:

```
dict1 = {1: ['BB', 'CC', 'DD'], 2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG']}
result = {}
for k,v in dict1.items():
    if "BB" in v:
        v.remove("BB")
        result["BB"] = [k] + v
    else:
        result[k] = v
print(result)
```

result:

```
{'BB': [1, 'CC', 'DD'], 2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG']}
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Solution?

Here some kind of a solution? *(not as i would desire it to be but it does the job)* :

```py
dict1 = {1: ['BB', 'CC', 'DD'], 2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG']}

for key in list(dict1):
    for i, value in enumerate(dict1[key]):
        if value == 'BB':
            dict1[value] = dict1.pop(key)
            dict1[value][i] = key

print(dict1)
```

```
{2: ['FF', 'HH', 'GG'], 'BB': [1, 'CC', 'DD']}
```

<sup>***^^^⚠️ The sequence is changed ⚠️***</sup>

### References:

- [How to avoid “RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941855/11465149)
- [Does enumerate create a copy of its argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015166/11465149)
- [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406521/11465149)
- [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082739/11465149)
- [Why can’t you modify list's items directly through "for in" loops in Python?](https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-you-modify-lists-through-for-in-loops-in-Python)

> You can’t use for-in loop to modify a list because the iteration variable, *(item in your example)*, is only holding the value from your list and not directly pointing to that particular list item...

- [How to reference a dict object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205017/how-to-reference-a-dict-object)